# Is there any benefit to writing aria-required="false"?

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria

Is there any benefit to writing `aria-required="false"` or is it best only to add `aria-required="true"` as needed and otherwise leave it off?

I have struggled to find any clarification on this in the WCAG docs I have read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For simplicity, I always leave off the attribute rather than setting it to *false* even if *false* is the default value.  *Most*(*) of the time you're ok either way.  From a javascript perspective, sometimes it's easier to use a conditional (ternary) operator rather than remove the attribute.

```js
disabled = obj.getAttribute('aria-disabled');
obj.setAttribute('aria-disabled', disabled ? "false" : "true");

/* versus */

disabled = obj.getAttribute('aria-disabled');
if (disabled) 
  obj.removeAttribute('aria-disabled')
else 
  obj.setAttribute('aria-disabled', "true");
```

*Sometimes* there's a note in the doc to **not** do this, as with [`aria-hidden`](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-hidden)

> **Note** 
> At the time of this writing, `aria-hidden="false"` is known to work inconsistently in browsers. As future implementations improve, use caution and test thoroughly before relying on this approach.

(*) There are a few aria- attributes where you **do** have to set the value specifically to *true* or *false* because setting it to *false* is **not** the same as *not* having the attribute, such as `aria-expanded`, `aria-pressed`, `aria-checked`, `aria-selected`.  For example, *not* having `aria-expanded` doesn't have any meaning but having `aria-expanded="false"` means you have an expandable/collapsable section that is currently collapsed.   *Not* having `aria-checked` doesn't have any meaning but having `aria-checked="false"` means you have a checkbox that is unchecked.

With `aria-required`, since it's value will typically not change once it's set (unlike the four attributes just mentioned which *do* typically change based on user interaction), I keep the code simple and just don't have the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Adding onto the answer by slugolicious, if in React, you can pass an empty value and the attribute will be omitted, ie. `aria-required={required}`, and required is `undefined` or `null`.

If required is `false` (boolean) and you want to omit it, use an `or` operator `aria-required={required || undefined}`

As for the original question, I see it as redundant to set the attribute to "false", and it doesn't add any value in terms of functionality or accessibility.